# Angular 8 Component change and ngOnInit call

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have 2 components inside a main component . Both having forms with input fields and span elements. User are provisioned to edit the form using edit button or cancel the editing using cancel button. 
So I need to cancel the edit status off whenever the user changes the tab without clicking cancel. Means need to trigger an event once the component is changed  or called in order to false the ecit status. I could not get anything yet. Seem like a simple issue.

Structure shown as below

```
<accordion [isAnimated]="true">
<accordion-group heading="Basic Details">
    <div class="profiletab_detail_wrp">
        <app-basic-details></app-basic-details>
    </div>
</accordion-group>
<accordion-group heading="Address Details">
    <div class="profiletab_detail_wrp">
        <app-address-details></app-address-details>
    </div>
</accordion-group>
```

Comment: Which library you are using for generating accordion-groups?

Comment: currently using ngx bootstrap 5.2.0

Comment: I have modified the answer for ngx-bootstrap, please give a try.

Answer (score 1):

Ngx-bootstrap accordion having an event called `(isOpenChange)`, to be fired whenever a accordion getting toggled. So give a try like this.

**HTML**

```
<accordion [closeOthers]="oneAtATime"
   <accordion-group heading="Basic Details" (isOpenChange)="onBasicInfoToggle($event)">
       <div class="profiletab_detail_wrp">
           <app-basic-details></app-basic-details>
       </div>
   </accordion-group>
<accordion>
```

**Component**

```
onBasicInfoToggle(event) {
  // Turn of the edit mode maybe like
  if(event === 'closed') {
      this.editMode = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am only trying this out.I will let you know my findings here. Nothing can be done    
even if we get an event once the tab is changed. Because I need to pass this data to the component and call the event on that component in order to turn of the edit status (means hide the input fields). All the fields are on that component. Not in the parent component.  My main issue is I cant invoke the ngOninit function everytime the component changes. I guess I am making sense to you. If not let me know your queries.

Comment: @SandyB `ngOnInit` will be only invoked when the component renders first time, or when it get destroyed and created again. Along with the above solution, you can use `Input` & `Output` decoraters in order to parent->child / child->parent communications. Also use `ngOnSimpleChanges` to watch out the status changes on `Input()`.

Comment: Or if nothing helps, please create a stackblitz to rectify the problem.

Comment: I will update it once i implemented the 'ngOnSimpleChanges',input & output decorators.

Comment: I have implemented Input decorator and also receives the input in ngonchanges and now it works. Now whenever user go to another tab without canceling edited state , and coming back to the same component edited state will beturned off. But it only works once. I cant repeat the process. No calls are getting in ngOnChanges on the second time. Now i only did the parent -> child. I think i need to child->parent event emitting as well . Let me know your thoughts and queries

Comment: ngOnChanges not getting invoked when i do the same process again. Thats where I am stuck at right now.

Comment: @SandyB Can you quickly create a stackblitz with minimal code to describe the problem that occurs now? I am sure, It can be resolved within minutes.

Comment: Thanks Sathosh for the concern. In order to invoke ngOnchanges everytime i passed a random value to child from parent. Now its working. I was passing a constant number in the input decorator. ngOnchanges wont get invoked if the value does not change i guess. Can You suggest a better solution? I will create a stackblitz shortly. In the meant time if i am making sense,respond with your thoughts

Comment: @SandyB Right, `ngOnChanges` won't mind if `new value === old value`. But I am hoping to solve this with better solution after creating stackblitz.

Comment: Allirght. I will update you once i set up the stackblitz.